# Proper way to convert a method to async that calls Write forty times?

Tags: c#, file-io, async-await

I have a method that blits specially formatted data out to a file as fast as `StreamWriter` can write. At this point there are many separate calls to `StreamReader.Write` because this was found to be faster than string concatenation/buffering on top of the buffering `StreamWriter` already does.

So the question is, do I await all forty Write calls, most of which write one to ten characters each? This seems ugly.

Can I ensure that nothing is flushed until I call `FlushAsync`? If I use synchronous writes and then call `FlushAsync` at the end, would that possibly defeat the `StreamWriter` buffering strategy?

The end goal is 1) no lag in the user interface, 2) save the file as quickly as possible. It's a large amount of data.

Comment: Are the forty write calls all writing to the same file? If so, does it matter what order the writes actually occur in?

Comment: Yes, the order is crucial. It's a multi-Write version of string.Format, purely for performance reasons.

Comment: Do you need async IO at all? It is often more CPU intensive. Maybe just run this synchronously on a thread-pool task?

Comment: @usr: CPU intensive? I wouldn't have guessed that. It's basically a WaitHandle, right?
Otoh I'm accessing non-thread-safe data, through no choice of my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need async IO at all? It is often more CPU intensive (just like in your case - you're right about that). Just run the IO work on a thread-pool thread using synchronous IO. That could look like this:

```
await Task.Run(() => MyIOFunction());
```

you have no concurrency issues to fear because `await` pauses the rest of the program until the background thread is done.

Async IO is not based on waiting. The OS calls you back when the IO is done. It tends to use more CPU. Async IO is for unblocking the UI in a convenient way and for scaling. It is not helpful for CPU efficiency.

Comment: This may be my solution. I'll have to do more work up front since the third party data component is not thread safe. I'm still curious how `async` would be done, though.

Comment: For async, my strategy would be to plug in a `BufferedStream` with a big buffer. When the buffer is not nearly full, you can do synchronous writes at full speed. When the buffer has little space left, you flush asynchronously. The performance cost of this is just a little memcpy. Not too bad.; The ADO.NET team had a similar problem. If you want fully async reads you have to execute one `await` *per column read*. This quickly gets very slow. I believe they now buffer an entire row so that you don't have to do this.

Comment: I like that idea. I could make a stream that has a dedicated thread to do the writing and manage the buffer size and call Write from any other thread without worry of causing a flush on the calling thread.

Comment: No need for a separate thread. Just say `await bufferedStream.FlushAsync();`. You can mix sync and async IO in the same function (with care).

Answer (score 0):

I would do it the following way, if that fits your logic:

1. set [`streamWriter.AutoFlush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush) to `false`
2. do the writes "synchrounous"
3. call `await streamWriter.FlushAsync()`

This should do all filling of the buffer as fast as your CPU/Memory can do it and then frees the thread, while it is actually written to the disk. Keep in mind, that nothing is written to the disk until you manually call `Flush` or `FlushAsyn` in case e.g. an exception occurs.

As the order does matter you can't run the writes in parallel, but you may can put the whole operation into a `Task` running in the background if that helps your program flow:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        streamWriter.AutoFlush = false;
        // write to writer
        await streamWriter.FlushAsync();
    });
```

Comment: With AutoFlush `false`, StreamWriter.Write will never call Stream.Flush. It will, however call Stream.Write when the StreamWriter's buffer is full. The FileStream (or whatever stream it is) might then have to flush its own buffer. I can't predict which call to Write might cause the buffers to flush.

Comment: And you can't control the underlying stream?

Comment: Right now I'm using a FileStream. I suppose I could build my own implementation of FileStream, or for that matter, of StreamWriter. Hoping that there is already a simple way to handle this.

Comment: `StreamWriter` does take any form of stream - you could even use a `MemoryStream` at first and then "manually dump it to a file at once"...

Comment: So the answer is basically roll your own buffer?

Comment: I am still not shure, what yiour "end goal" is. Can you may add some more explanation to the question? Also read @usr's answer - these are valid points if you are aiming for performance...